# Trigger a website when a chrome extension is turned on/off

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

My current implementation is in my react component's `useEffect` I have a `setInterval` function which runs every 1 second to run `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` to listen to chrome extension and in my background script of chrome extension I send the message.

This method runs continuously, I need a method to only trigger the website whenever a change in the extension happens (like turn on/off, allow incognito, etc.).

I searched for any tools to monitior the extension but nothing helped. There are some website which listens for adblocks, I need something like that.

Comment: It's unclear where this code runs as extensions have many different contexts.

Comment: it is a google chrome extension when turned on can interact with the website front-end which I am developing in react. A specific code in the front-end need to be triggered when a change in extension happens.

Comment: Please clarify which code runs in contexts like content script, action popup, background script (service worker).

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired functionality of triggering your website only when a change occurs in your Chrome extension (such as turning it on/off or allowing incognito), you can utilize the Chrome Extension Messaging API to establish communication between your extension's background script and your website.

Here's an approach you can follow:

1.Modify your extension's background script: In your background script, listen for events or changes within your extension using the appropriate Chrome extension APIs. For example, you can use the chrome.runtime.onMessage event listener to detect when a message is sent from your website or other extension components.

2.Send a message from the background script: When a relevant change occurs in your extension, such as turning it on/off or changing incognito settings, use the chrome.runtime.sendMessage method to send a message to your website.

3.Update your React component: Instead of continuously running the chrome.runtime.sendMessage in a setInterval within your React component's useEffect, you can use the chrome.runtime.onMessage event listener in your component to listen for messages sent from the extension's background script.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Listen for messages sent from the extension's background script
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
      if (message.extensionChange === true) {
        // Extension change detected, trigger your website accordingly
        // Add your logic here
        console.log('Extension change detected');
      }
    });

    return () => {
      // Cleanup: Remove the message listener when the component is unmounted
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener();
    };
  }, []);

  // Rest of your component code
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it really helped me. but I think I need to periodically check for any extension changes from by background script.